# Open-CV - Not loading correctly

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to compile this code, but I get these errors no matter what, I believe it has something to do with including the OpenCV library, but I'm not sure. Could anyone help me out?
Errors:

> main.cc:66:37: error: ‘CV_RETR_EXTERNAL’ was not declared in this scope
>
> main.cc:66:55: error: ‘CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE’ was not declared in this scope
>
> main.cc:81:28: error: ‘CV_BGR2GRAY’ was not declared in this scope

The Code(sorry for the formatting, I just can't get this right):

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <iostream>
void rgb2cmyk(cv::Mat& src, std::vector<cv::Mat>& cmyk)
{
CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_8UC3);

cmyk.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cmyk.push_back(cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_32F));

for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j)
    {
        cv::Vec3b p = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j);

        float r = p[2] / 255.;
        float g = p[1] / 255.;
        float b = p[0] / 255.;
        float k = (1 - std::max(std::max(r,g),b));

        cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k); 
        cmyk[1].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
        cmyk[2].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);
        cmyk[3].at<float>(i,j) = k;
    }
}
}

int main()
{
cv::Mat im0 = cv::imread("scratchcard.png");
if (!im0.data)
    return -1;

std::vector<cv::Mat> cmyk;
rgb2cmyk(im0, cmyk);

cv::Mat im1;
im1 = cmyk[3].mul(1 - cmyk[1]) > 0.25;

cv::Mat im2;
im1.convertTo(im2, CV_8U);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(im2, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

double max_area = 0;
int max_idx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    max_idx  = area > max_area ? i : max_idx;
    max_area = area > max_area ? area : max_area;
}

im2.setTo(cv::Scalar(0));
cv::drawContours(im2, contours, max_idx, cv::Scalar(255), -1);

cv::Mat im3;
cv::cvtColor(im0, im3, CV_BGR2GRAY);
im3 = ((255 - im3) & im2) > 200;

cv::Mat dst = im3.clone();
cv::findContours(dst.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (cv::contourArea(contours[i]) < 100)
        cv::drawContours(dst, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0), -1);
}

tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
tess.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
tess.SetImage((uchar*)dst.data, dst.cols, dst.rows, 1, dst.cols);

char* out = tess.GetUTF8Text();
std::cout << out << std::endl;

cv::imshow("src", im0);
cv::imshow("dst", dst);
cv::waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: CV_RETR_EXTERNAL and CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE errors were fixed by using cv::"whatever".
However, CV_BGR2GRAY error persists, if changed to cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY the whole code gets highlighted as buggy. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Did you try ::CV_RETR_EXTERNAL instead of CV_RETR_EXTERNAL?

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? CV_RETR_EXTERNAL is from the C API, so it might not exist. Try cv::RETR_EXTERNAL instead -- it should exist if your setup is correct.

Comment: Arelius and ypnos, I' using the latest OpenCV version (2.4.9 if i'm not wrong). I'll test your solutions as soon is i get to my Ubuntu pc.

Comment: Using cv::RETR_EXTERNAL fixed part of it, i still get `main.cc:82:27: error: ‘BGR2GRAY’ is not a member of ‘cv’`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

it seems, you are (accidentally) using the 3.0(master) opencv branch.

a lot of constants have changed there, like most of the CV_ prefixes were changed to cv:: namespace, 
CV_BGR2GRAY is now cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY, etc.

also all module headers went one up, like opencv2/imgproc.hpp .

if you got the code from the github repo, and want to use the 2.4.9 branch instead,

```
git checkout 2.4
```

(in the opencv folder) will take you there. ofc you will have to rerun cmake and recompile

Comment: I'm running 2.4.9, and I just tested with 2.4.8, neither of them worked.

Answer (score 11):

Use `COLOR_RGB2GRAY` rather than `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`. It worked for me, though I am running OpenCV 3.0. You may have to use `cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY` as the others recommended, if you are running 2.4.

Comment: `cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY` worked for me in OpenCV 4.x